# Can viruses of one ssd transfer to another ssd?

Tags: virus, ssd

I have 2 ssds both with Windows 10. If I boot the 2nd ssd and start downloading infected files can my primary ssd be infected too?

Comment: yes, it would be

Answer (score 2):

Anything that runs on your computer (like a virus) has access to everything that the Operating System has access to. This might be limited in some locations by specific user permissions.

Some viruses can try to take over the whole computer so that it can access things that even the operating system cannot access, but those are rare.

So, yes, some viruses like to spread everywhere it can reach, some don't, but the safe assumption is that a virus does spread within a computer.

Answer (score 2):

## Yes, it can be.

If two devices are connected to the same machine, malware can infect either device.